# jquery .css script doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Morning,
I'm trying to display a div onmouseover. I created a function but i don't know what is wrong. Could you help me please.

The HTML code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="it">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title> PHOTOGALLERY</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/smoothness/jquery-ui-
         1.9.2.custom.css"/>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://malsup.github.com/jquery.cycle2.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-ui-1.9.2.custom.js">
    </script>
    <script>
        function show_img_container() {
            $("#image_container").css("display", "block");
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="div_container">
        <div id="div_image" class="cycle-slideshow">
            <img src="images/2.jpg" style="height:100%; width:100%">
            <img src="images/3.jpg" style="height:100%; width:100%">
            <img src="images/4.jpg" style="height:100%; width:100%">
            <img src="images/5.jpg" style="height:100%; width:100%">
        </div>
        <div id="image_container" onmouseover="show_img_container()"></div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

In the css file i have a image_container id where the attribute display is set to 'none';

Comment: I'm curious, is it possible to hover an element that is displayed as none?

Comment: It is better to attach CSS code than describing what you have written there

Comment: Also the code validation it's ok.

Comment: @Novice How can you hover an element in which you have displayed as none?

Comment: you are triggering an function on the element which is not displayed..

Comment: Agreed with @Swellar comment.

Comment: You say you have an element which has an ID named `image_container` displayed as none, yet you are putting the function to that element. Your function will not work because the element is not there at all.

Answer (score 3):

If you only want to show the `<div>` on hover you wouldn't need any `JS` you could try someting like this:

```css
div {
    display: none;
}
    
a:hover + div {
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<a>Hover over me!</a>
<div>Stuff shown on hover</div>
```

To explain further:
Since you're using `display: none;` on the container the mousehover won't take affect since the `<div>` can't be found by the event since it's not displaying in the first place.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 3):

> In the css file i have a image_container id where the attribute display is set to 'none';

It is not possible to hover a none blocked element.

You can use the opacity attribute to hide your div.

```css
div {
    opacity: 0;
}
    
div:hover {
    opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div>Stuff shown on hover</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You cant hover on div if its display is sets to none.

Comment: It should be a comment.

Comment: well that's why i downvoted. but seems like everybody else ( almost ) think this is worthy of an answer

Comment: @MihaiT, IMHO its worthy of answer

Comment: @Satpal an answer should give a solution. IMO. i think that's one of the reasons the comments were created. for ' answers ' such as these. But anyway, i respect others opinions

Comment: Im sorry im new on stack.. thank you for correcting me.

Comment: @MihaiT, No solution will work in this scenario, unless OP change the flow and I also respect your opinions

Comment: Everyone has a different opinion on comments and answers. In this case. This should be a comment. Because even tho you're telling the OP a mistake he has made (`display: none;`) on the `<div>` it doesn't give an answer to his question. The actual question is about the function and whats wrong with it. If he would change his `display` attribute on the `div` as told in your answer. it wouldn't give the solution OP is asking for. it would only show the div in it's normal state. As an answer this is wrong. As a comment this would be a great one. Take a look at my answer for an example.

Comment: I'm voting to leave this up. As the question is written, this is a valid answer, albeit could use improvement.

Answer (score 2):

I'll answer based on what OP has provided. wrap the `#image_container` with a `div` that contains the function, then it should work.

And since it's quite weird that something appeared when hovered but didn't disappear after hovering out, I added another function for `onmouseout`

```js
function show_img_container() {
  $("#image_container").css("display", "block");
}
function hide_img_container() {
  $("#image_container").css("display", "none");
}
```

```css
#image_container {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div onmouseover="show_img_container()" onmouseout="hide_img_container()">
  HOVER ME!!
  <div id="image_container">IM HIDDEN!!!</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Ok. I know the problem. In the css stylesheet i had this:

```
#image_container {
position: absolute;
height: 120px;
width: 100%;
bottom: 5%;
background-color: black;
opacity: 0;
**transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out 2s;**
z-index: 1;

}

#image_container:hover {
opacity: 1;
}
```

If i delete the transition attribute it works:`
Could you show me why?

Comment: try `transistion: opacity 0.3s ease-in-out 2s;`